# Reference, Object, LinkedList

Tags: java

So I am building a `LinkedList` from scratch. Though the code works, I am confused on two things.

When you write (`public node root`) you are creating a reference to the object? In other words is this a pointer? If yes, in the method `add()` I check to see if root `equals` to `null` for the first iteration, which it is and the code creates a instance of that class.

My problem comes in method `Find()`. When root is `null`, and I set `temp1=root`, isn't `temp1` also going to be `null` since `root` is `null`? Or `temp1` is pointing to `root` and `root` is pointing to `null`? How different are these?

Edit: if temp1 is null then why is method find() working?

```
public class LinkedList {

    public Node root;

    public void add(int data) {
        if(root == null) {
            root = new Node(data);          
        }
        else {
            Node temp1 = root;
            Node temp = new Node(data);

            while(temp1.getNext() != null) {
                temp1 = temp1.getNext();
            }

            temp1.setNext(temp);                    
        }       
    }

    public boolean Find(int data) {
        Node temp1 = root;

        while(temp1 != null) {
            if(temp1.getData() == data) {
                return true;
            }
            temp1 = temp1.getNext();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are calling `Find()` then you have probably already called `add()` so `root` is no longer null.

Comment: you mean if I call root to use in Find() I am Calling it from add()? I thought it's called from the top..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "if I call root". `root` is just a variable and you do not "call" it. I'm saying that if you have a LinkedList instance and you call the `Find()` method then the list probably has something in it from calling the `add()` method previously which means root is no longer null because it gets a value the first time `add()` is called.. Even if you didn't call `add()` first, your `Find()` has a null check to prevent exceptions.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong! At the top of the code I declare a root, the root is a pointer and as of that line its pointing to null, now if I temp1=root inst temp1 also going to be null since root is null?

Comment: Yes, if root is null then `temp1 = root` is the same as `temp1 = null`. This will happen if you try to `Find()` something in an empty list. Since `Find()` has a null check this does not cause exceptions.

Comment: what you'r saying is if I didn't have the method add() the method Find() would always be false?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You cannot find something in an empty list...

Comment: Okay good! Now we are in the same page. My problems is I can't understand how root is not going to be null. How is the add() method effecting this variable. Isn't it true that each method does it's own job? This is where I am lost.

Comment: `root` was declared at the class level so it is available to all the methods inside that class, all the methods are using the same one. It is possible to create a variable that only exists within the method but in this example that is not the case.

Comment: For example, `temp` is a variable that is only available inside the `add()` method.

Comment: When i declare root, I declare it for all methods, meaning any method is going to be able to use it. We also agreed that if the method add() is not in the code the method Find() will always be false. The problem is HOW? HOW is add() effecting Find()? Is it because since I use root in add() now root has the same pointer in Find()?

Comment: Since it's a global variable each time i make a change to it, in a method, and bring it out of the method, will the data inside that variable will also be brought out?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant when I said all the methods are using the same one. `add` gives a value and `Find` can see it.

Comment: Holy shit I didn't know that. Thank you for clearing that out.

Comment: Sure thing. You might want to look at some tutorials for debuggers as you can see exactly what every line of code is doing as it does it.

Comment: I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Any object-valued variable in Java is actually a reference to the actual object that is stored on the heap.

In your `Find` method, you're assigning the reference to `root` to `temp1`, you now essentially have 2 references to the same `Node` object.

If you call `Find` before calling `add`, `root` (and `temp1` since they refer to the same object) are `null` so this function will always return `false.`

Only after calling `add`, where a reference to a `Node` object will be assigned to `root`, will it be possible for it to return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

> When you write (public node root) you are creating a reference to the object?

Yes. You're declaring an object reference of type Node. Since you are not initializing this, the reference value is null.  Java references are like pointers in other languages, although there are some key differences. Like a pointer, the value of an object reference will be a memory address that contains your object. Unlike some other languages, you can't do pointer arithmetic with Java references.

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/typesValues.html#4.3) has this to say about the issue:

> The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these
>   objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

I was initially making a more syntactic argument, but after going back to the JLS, I agree that references are pointers, even though C-Style pointer operations aren't supported in Java.

> When root is null, and I set temp1=root, isn't temp1 also going to be null since root is null?

Yes, temp will be assigned the value of root. That is, it will reference the same Node instance that root is currently referencing. If root is null when this call is made, then temp1 will also be null.

In your code, you *could* (probably should) initialize your root Node in a constructor like so. This will initialize your root node each time you call new LinkedList() in some other method. Note that I made a couple other minor changes to make this class conform more closely to :

```
public class LinkedList {

    // made this private
    // be sure to add get/set methods to access/change this value 
    // if needed outside this class
    private Node root;

    // default (no-arg) constructor
    public LinkedList() {
      root = new Node();
    }

    public void add(int data) {
      Node temp1 = root;
      Node temp = new Node(data);

      while(temp1.getNext() != null) {
          temp1 = temp1.getNext();
      }

      temp1.setNext(temp);                    
    }

    public boolean find(int data) {
        Node temp1 = root;

        while(temp1 != null) {
            if(temp1.getData() == data) {
                return true;
            }
            temp1 = temp1.getNext();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do this aren't we going to have a extra node that the data would be 0. I think by doing this I will have a node that I didn't declare. At least that what my compiler is showing.